# C# MVVM pattern update UI in Infinite loop thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I have a background thread to listen data, so this infinite loop to output data.

And, I using a `ObservableCollection` to bind a `ListBox` and show log.

I try to use `Dispather.BeginInvoke`, but no use, it not realtime. I have no idea for update UI in MVVM.

xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="lsb_log" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayLogs}"/>
```

code

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _displayLogs;
public ObservableCollection<string> DisplayLogs
{
     get
     {
         return _displayLogs;
     }
}

public Testpro()
{
    _displayLogs = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    Task.Run(new Action(outputData));
}

private void outputData()
{
    string str = "";
    while (true)
    {
        string newString = GetInfoString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newString) || str == newString)
            continue;

        str = newString;

        Debug.WriteLine(str);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
        {
                DisplayLogs.Add(str);
        });
    }
}
```

*Edit:

`GetInfoString` will call by a dll file.

Comment: what seems to be the question ?

Comment: I use Dispatcher but can't update UI in realtime.

Comment: Your loop is spinning far too fast for WPF to update properly, you should probably sleep your thread for a few milliseconds at the end of the loop.  Have you considered a [`DispatchTimer`](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/dispatchertimer/) instead of an infinite loop in a separate thread? It would be simpler code.

Comment: Thanks, I never use DispatchTimer, maybe I can try it.

Comment: @BradleyUffner  Please don't ever sleep threads. There are much better ways to do it.

Comment: @Enigmativity there are valid reasons to sleep threads, especially background threads. Obviously sleeping the UI thread is a horrible idea though, but the poster indicated that this is a background thread.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - Are those reasons valid here? If so what are they?

Comment: Your issue is that itemsSource is not hooking up the ObservableCollection's ColectionChanged event. Verify the issue by raise property change when you add new item to the collection and use this ItemsSource binding ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DisplayLog, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

Comment: @Enigmativity it's hard to say without knowing more about the poster's exact needs here, but from what I can see, sleeping this background thread for 10ms shouldn't cause any problems. It gives wpf enough time to detect application idle, and dispatch his queued requests. It isn't the UI thread, so it won't harm user interactivity at all. I *did* suggest using a DispatchTimer as a better alternative though.

Comment: @Bradley Uffner I try to sleep 10ms, but it always wait no data and show all once.

Comment: @cscmh99 I try add properties, but it's no use in my case. In fact, I update this ObservableCollection in other place, then it's OK.

Comment: What is your usecase ? Are u reading logs and want to display the lines ?

Comment: @FelixD. Yes, but I want to display realtime.

Comment: @FelixD. Your answer is use `DP.Invoke` to update UI, but it can not work in my case, I don't know why, this is my question.

Comment: It worked for me... Validate your code. This **should** work.

Comment: @FelixD. Oh.. Maybe `GetInfoString()` has something wrong. Thanks, I will check again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use something designed for this kind of update. I'm going to suggest Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive" & "System.Reacive.Windows.Threading").

Then you can do this after the `_displayLogs = new ObservableCollection<string>();` line:

```
IDisposable subscription = 
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Select(_ => GetInfoString())
        .Where(newString => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newString))
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .ObserveOnDispatcher()
        .Subscribe(newString =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(newString);
            DisplayLogs.Add(newString);
        });
```

That should call `GetInfoString()` every second and update your UI. It handles all of the threading and marshalling issues.

If you keep a reference to `subscription` you can stop it at any stage by calling `subscription.Dispose()`.

Comment: it always wait no data and show all once.

Comment: @黃柏森 - Sorry, do you mean you wait for all of the data and show it all at once? If so, your code in the question doesn't show any of that. Can you explain that more fully?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why, but `Debug.WriteLine` is work in realtime to show.

Comment: @黃柏森 - Sorry, I understand English isn't your first language, but I'm having difficulty understanding you. I do apologize.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's my fault. As you say, I wait for all of the data and show it all at once in UI, but the `Debug.WriteLine` show is normal. I think they should update at same time.

Comment: By the way, in my issue, I use `BeginInvoke`, then it show all at once, too. But all data are same result.

Comment: @黃柏森 - Have you tried my code?

Comment: Yes, it show all at once, too. But data is right.

Comment: @黃柏森 - It should show the data one at a time. Try changing `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)` to `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0)` and see if that shows the updating properly.

Comment: In my case, I need change TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0.1), the data is right. If I use 1(ms) or 1.0(s) or 10.0(s), the data will lose. ex. the right data sequence is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., If use 1(ms): 1, 3, 5, ....
But however, It always show all at once after no data.

Comment: @黃柏森 - Could you try adding the line `.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)` after the line `.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))`, but before the line `.Select(_ => GetInfoString())`?

Comment: OK, then it no different after I try it.

Comment: @黃柏森 - That seems unusual. It should be adding the items one at a time.

Comment: Yes, in the beginning, I think that Dispatcher will be cover my issue but it cant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use async-await therefore. Your OutputData-Method can look something like:

```
private async void OutputData(IProgress<string> onProgress)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        string str = string.Empty;

        while (true)
        {
            string newString = GetInfoString();
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newString) || str == newString)
                continue;

            str = newString;

            // call the UI to update your bound collection
            onProgress.Report(str);

            // give the ui some time to respond before continue with your endless-loop
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    });
}
```

And you can call this method with:

```
OutputData(new Progress<string>((str) =>
{
    DisplayLogs.Add(str);
}));
```

That's it

Comment: I am currently using such method and it causes Memory leak in my application